# Get the URL from button which clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to Jquery. I have a doubt:

For example, in a web page as voting, if you click a button, a counter is incremented by +1. Now, how to draw the url of the button on a website? Therefore, if we provide the url to others, and just click on the URL, the counter should increase by 1 on the website.

Best example of this is FaceBook LIKE.

I prefer to use jQuery, PHP and MySQL

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to vote on somebody else's website by directly accessing whatever URL is associated with the vote button from that site, instead of visiting the site like a normal user? (You'll probably find many modern websites don't have a URL directly associated to the voting process: obviously an up-vote image has a URL, but the voting process is most likely done in JavaScript via Ajax. Also the voting on sites like Stack Overflow is associated with your user account.)

Comment: You need to be much more specific :)

Comment: @nnnnnn Hi, just want to know the reason to proposed to close this question by someone? Person requesting a idea where it could be wrong? As a senior person copuld you answer this.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but whoever did picked the reason _"Not a real question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."_ In my previous comment I tried to clarify what you were asking, so perhaps you could read what I said and confirm if that is what you are trying to do (edit your question, don't clarify in the comments).

Comment: what is asked here? is it getting the button url? or how to vote off-site? how does jQuery fit in all of this? do you mean that every access to the URL means a +1 vote? it's a possible vote-spamming victim if you do voting via URL access only (without checks).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do it using ajax, and a server side program to record votes.

You could design the page with any look-and-feel. Then add the ajax code to talk to your server-side program and maybe show the user the current votes.

```
?id=642&point=1
```

It’s a POST, not a GET, so it could only be done from a form or AJAX, not a simple URL.

```
//Vote update
$.post(
    "http://example.com/folder/vote.php",     // url
    { id: 642, point : 1 },                   // post-data
    function(data){                           // response
        $("#resultBox").addClass("done");     // show msg
    }
);
```

More reading at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit difficult to understand what you're trying to ask but here's my take on it.

#### Scenario

You have a page at http://mywebsite.com/rating which contains 5 items you can rate on.

#### Solution

There are two events here that point to the same server side code.

What you need to do is assign an identifier to your button/product/whatever you're trying to rate. So you might have something like this `<button ratingname="button1">Rate me!</button>`

Now you will have a jQuery function that will use AJAX to communicate with your server and store the increment in the database. This jQuery function will be invoked via an event handler for the button and by going to this url: http://mywebsite.com/rating#button1.

Once your page loads you should check the hash for a value and if one is found then invoke the original jQuery function. You may want to additionally check if the value for the hash is a valid rating button value. (Note you could also use a query string).